# Docker Windows 10 hosted volume - not creating files

Tags: windows, docker, volume

I'm trying to create a MySQL docker container using docker-compose, using the following config file..

```
version: '2'

services:  
  # Name of the service as Docker will reference.
mysqlDb:

# The image, change 5.7 to any of the supported docker versions.
image: mysql:latest

# Required environment variables.  Creates a Database with a
# root user, non-root user both with passwords.
#
# MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD defines the root password of the root user
# MYSQL_DATABASE names the DB
# MYSQL_USER is the non-root user
# MYSQL_PASSWORD is the non-root user password
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pascal01"
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "swot"

# What port do you want this MySQL instance to be available on?
# The left hand number is what port it will be available on from your machine
# perspective.  The right hand number is the post that it's linking up to.
# In this case we're saying "link our local 3306 to the docker container's 3306"
# which works here, because docker MySQL exposes the MySQL DB to the container's
# 3306 port.  If we wanted this available on port 3307 on our local machine
# we'd change this to 3307:3306
ports:
  - 3306:3306

# We're using a named volume here that docker manages for us.  This is a special
# place just for this particular dockerized MySQL instance.
volumes:
  - d:/ian/data/swot:/var/lib/mysql
```

When I ran this the first time, everything was fine. A bunch of files were created in the Windows 10 folder. After that I went into the 'D;/ian/data/swot' windows folder and deleted all the files created by MySQL.

Thereafter,  when I re-run the docker-compose process it is NOT creating the MySQL files in the host folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Norton filewall blocking access.  but there is nothing in the docker container output to the commmand line that would indicate this.